# "Check All" vs "Build/ReBuild All" in GeoTest ATEasy software development environment

Tags: build, compilation, ateasy

I am using `ATEasy` software development environment to develop automatic tests.

The `ATEasy` version is `6-136b`.

In one of the projects I use a third party driver that is password protected, so I cannot look at its code.

when I want to compile and check for errors (by clicking `Check All`) I am getting:

```
Compiling ...
ST
System
A2D
Compiler error #570: Expected integer expression, found in 'A2D.API_RemoteRegister' in line 3
```

But, when I am trying to compile & build the project (by clicking `Build` or `Rebuild all`), I get this:

```
    ------ Rebuild All started: Project: ST ------
Compiling ...
ST
System
A2D
No Errors

Creating 'D:\ST.exe' ...
Done.
```

When I run the `ST.EXE` everything works fine.

How can it be? In both cases, I see that it compiles the code (`Compiling ...`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question in the ATEasy forum and got this replay:

> Check All - checks all procedure no matter if they were referenced in your project. 
>   Build and Rebuild All - only checks your project referenced procedures. 
>   Since in your project you are not calling API_RemoteRegister the error you have will not shown.

I checked a little further and found out that if there are no references to a function, the compiler dosent add it to the compilation.

If you want to add a function to the compilation anyway you can do it by:

right click the function --> properties --> check "compile"